# Uninstall mongodb correctly and install mongodb again

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

Please teach me how to uninstall my mongodb in my virtualbox(ubuntu).

I tried these command and nothing was removed :

```
sudo apt-get purge mongodb mongodb-clients mongodb-server mongodb-dev
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-10gen
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

It still exists.
I type `mongod --version`   it shows  `db version v2.6.1`

Update:

I want to remove it and then install it again:

I tried the following 4 commands -

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mongodb-org
```

then
    sudo service mongod start

and type `mongo`  there is error:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.4
connecting to: test
2014-09-02T21:27:10.390+0800 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111     Connection refused
2014-09-02T21:27:10.392+0800 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146
exception: connect failed
```

Did I miss something?
Please help me.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 11):

Normally, with apt command, you can launch autoremove with all mongoDB packages :

```
sudo apt-get autoremove mongodb-*
```

Ok on the mongodb documentation, the packages are changed. To have an up-to-date package follow instructions :

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
```

Create the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list` list file using the following command:

```
echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
```

Issue the following command to reload the local package database:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And install desired packages :

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb-org
```

After that you have server, shell, mongos, ...  To launch mongodb-server youcan launch the mongodb service like this :

```
sudo service mongod start
```

To connect on your local server just enter this command :

```
mongo
```

Comment: thanks!it really help me.btw.do you know how to install mongo db? I try the steps in the mongodb website.But terminal still said: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused

Comment: Did you run "sudo service mongod start" after installing it? It doesn't start automatically.

Comment: what happened when: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10  .it seems like this command didn't do things

Comment: this command is for accept the extern apt repository because it's not add with the command add apt-repository

Answer (score 3):

**To remove Mongo run  these commands below**

```
sudo apt-get purge mongodb
sudo rm -r /var/log/mongodb
sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongodb
```

**If you have different versions of mongo already  installed, Run the command below**

```sh
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

**To install mongo safely in Ubuntu 18.04 first update all packages by running this command**

```
sudo apt update
```

**Now install mongo**

```
sudo apt install -y mongodb
```

**Start mongo by running command below**

```
sudo systemctl start mongodb
```

**Now check mongodb status by running**

```
sudo systemctl status mongodb
```

It should show a status Active

**I hope this works for you thanks**