# MongoDB won't connect on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mongodb, shell, ubuntu

I am trying to install MongoDB on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I am following the article at the link below:

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Everything is fine, and my log file shows the following line:

```
2016-12-18T20:47:19.476+0000 I NETWORK [thread1] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

I also get the following status when i run the following command:

```
bitnami@ip-172-31-58-13:service mongod status
bitnami@ip-172-31-58-13:mongod start/running, process 15587
```

however, as soon as i try to connect to mongo, I run into an error, which I simply cannot seem to resolve.

Command:

```
bitnami@ip-172-31-58-13:/var/log/mongodb$ mongo
```

Output:

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.7
connecting to: /opt/bitnami/mongodb/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock:27017/test
2016-12-19T00:08:48.809+0000 W NETWORK Failed to connect to /opt/bitnami/mongodb/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock:0, reason: errno:2 No such file or directory
2016-12-19T00:08:48.810+0000 E QUERY Error: couldn't connect to server /opt/bitnami/mongodb/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock:27017 (/opt/bitnami/mongodb/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock), connection attempt failed
at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:181:14)
at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:181
exception: connect failed
bitnami@ip-172-31-58-13:/var/log/mongodb$
```

I have tried everything on the internet (gone through about 50+ articles) but nothing seems to work - changing the .lock file, updating the permissions, even uninstalled and re-installed mongodb 2 times and so on.

I noticed that the mongodb-27017.sock is placed under /tmp rather than /opt/bitnami/mongodb/tmp/ but I am not sure if that is a problem?

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Thank you

Comment: I remember I counted the similar problem, but forgot exactly how I addressed it. Have you created a mongo user? If so, try `mongo` with that username and password.

Comment: No, I dont have authentication enabled, it's turned of by default as far as my knowledge goes.

Comment: No, I dont have authentication enabled, it's turned of by default as far as my knowledge goes.

If you look at the answer in this post, it tells to just type in "mongo" to connect to the database.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25624247/uninstall-mongodb-correctly-and-install-mongodb-again/25624284#25624284